# How can I add second x axis labels to a bar plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, facet-wrap, x-axis

I am trying to produce a graph similar to the one below:
[graph with two x axis labels, facet wrap and different colours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ur31N.png)

The format of my data is as follows:[Data format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5LYd.png)

The code that I have been using is:

```
data$x1 <- as.factor(data$x1)
data$x2 <- as.factor(data$x2)
data$Fill <- as.factor(data$Fill)

ggplot(data, aes(x=x1, y=y, fill=x2))+
  geom_col(position=position_dodge())+
  theme( legend.position = "right")+
  facet_wrap(~Sex, nrow=1, strip.position = "top")+
  theme(strip.placement = "outside")
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c(11, 12, 22),labels = c("11", "12", "22"))+
  ylab("y")
```

This produces the following plot:[Plot from above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVFxx.png)

However, I am unable to add x2 as a second variable on the x axis nor am I able to then use Fill as the fill= option.  Does anyone have a solution?

Kind regards

I have googled the issue and played around with the code but without success.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `position_dodge` one approach would be to create a new column by pasting your `x1` and `x2` columns together separated by a line break and mapping this new column on `x`. This way you will automatically get your two rows of axis labels. Tricky first part is to put the labels in the right order for which I use `arrange` to order the dataset first and second use `forcats::fct_inorder` to convert to a factor and setting the right order. A drawback of this approach is that the space between each bar is the same and groups of bars are no longer separated.

And as you already facetted by `Sex` there is no easy fix for that. One approach would be to use `facet_grid` or as I do below, to use `ggh4x::facet_nested_wrap` to facet by both `Sex` and `x1` then get rid of the strips for `x1`. Drawback of this approach is that it leaves some blank space.

Using some fake example data:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

# Example data
data <- expand.grid(
  Sex = 1:2,
  x1 = c("11", "12", "22"),
  x2 = c("11", "12", "22")
) |>
  dplyr::mutate(
    Fill = purrr::map2_chr(x1, x2, \(x, y) paste0(sort(c(x, y)), collapse = "")),
    Fill = as.numeric(factor(Fill)) - 1,
    y = seq_len(dplyr::n())
  )

data$x1 <- as.factor(data$x1)
data$x2 <- as.factor(data$x2)
data$Fill <- as.factor(data$Fill)

data <- data |>
  arrange(Sex, x1, x2) |>
  mutate(
    x = paste(x2, x1, sep = "\n"),
    x = forcats::fct_inorder(x)
  )

ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = Fill)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_nested_wrap(~ Sex + x1,
    nrow = 1,
    scales = "free_x",
    strip = ggh4x::strip_nested(
      by_layer_x = TRUE,
      text_x = list(element_text(), element_blank()),
      background_x = list(element_rect(), element_blank())
    )
  ) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, .8))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Stefan, Many thanks for your help!  I have applied your code to the data and it works.    As an R novice, I can't say I understand it all but I now have a starting point to look up the various commands and what they do.